# Matlab Parallel Computing with Simulink Model

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, simulation, simulink, parfor

I'm working on a project in which parallel computing would be a huge advantage. The project simulates multiple `Simulink` models. I did the simulation with a normal for-Loop, but since it takes days to simulate I decided to try the `"parfor"-Loop`.

But that's where the problem begins. First I'll give you pictures of my code, the workspace and the `Simulink-part` which is causing me problems:

[image: Code & Workspace]

[image: From Workspace block]

### Here's my code:

```
apool = gcp('nocreate');

if isempty(apool)

apool = parpool('local'); 

end

wpath = pwd;

parfor k = 1:number_of_models  

    load_system(strcat(wpath,'\Models_Folder\',House(k).model_name));
    set_param(House(k).model_name, 'Stoptime', num2str(foreruntime));
    set_param(House(k).mask_name, 'Data_contr', num2str(controlvector(k)));
    set_param(House(k).mask_name, 'Data_cons', strcat('GlobalData(',num2str(k),').consume.',MaskParam(k).consume_input))
    SimOut(k) = sim(House(k).model_name);
end

delete(apool);
```

The confusing thing is if i delete the column:

```
 SimOut(k) = sim(House(k).model_name);
```

the code just works fine -> the `modelparameters` are set in a `parfor loop`

but if I don't delete the column the following error appears:

> `Error using Forerunsimple (line 9)`
>
> `Error evaluating parameter 'Data_cons' in 'model_house_14/House'`

```
Caused by:

    Error using parallel_function>make_general_channel/channel_general (line 907)
    Error evaluating parameter 'Data_cons' in 'model_house_14/House'
    Error using parallel_function>make_general_channel/channel_general (line 907)
    Undefined variable "GlobalData" or class "GlobalData".
```

As you can see in the picture the variable `"GlobalData"` is defined in the workspace. So in my opinion it should work. Obviously it doesn't. Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Hi Elias, welcome to SO! Nice post you did, but you must consider posting the code as text in your question, instead as a screenshot!

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Sure posting the code as text makes much more sense, I'll keep that in mind. I'm pretty new to SO and Matlab-Simulink-Coding so forgive my unawareness about some things :)

Comment: Yes of course, no problem to me. Old ones here should help newcomers. Be aware that some are tough though. Don't take offenses personally.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to see this question, IMHO, it is related, and could in fact be the same problem:

[MATLAB: What happens for a global variable when running in the parallel mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715263/matlab-what-happens-for-a-global-variable-when-running-in-the-parallel-mode)

There a workspace global variable appears to be empty, even if it was defined.

user [Edric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88076/edric) provides a link, and a short explanation, that global variables are not passed to workers (for instance simulink running as parallel).

The link is to this blog entry: "Getting parfor loops up and running":
http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/02/using-parfor-loops-getting-up-and-running/

Comment: Thanks Henrik,
I'll read the question. But actually i'm not using a global variable. Initially i tried but I assumed it is a bad idea. So "GlobalData" is just a normal struct with Data-Arrays inside.
The Funny thing is i can acces the GlobalData files inside the parfor-Loop. I can display the data for example with "fprintf" inside the parfor-Loop. But if the simulation wants to access the GlobalData inside the parfor-Loop the error occurs :/

Comment: I just read the article and i think it's not excatly the same problem :/

Well i can even generate a variable with the data inside the parfor-Loop and it doesn't work. Here's a simplified code example:

>parfor i=1:20
  Temp = load('someData.mat')
  set_param(model, 'Data_cons', 'Temp')
  simout = sim(model)
end

fore some reason the model cant finde the Temp-variable...

Comment: Ok, never saw that before, and does not currently have a matlab installation with a simulink license, so .. :(

Comment: No Problem. Here's a link to a newer question, which is simplified:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747380/simulink-simulation-with-parfor-parallel-computing